# Wordpress and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have this code in my header.php for Wordpress to display a mini feed at the top of the page or not.

```
<?php if ( !$noHeader ) { include('feed.php'); } ?>
```

At the top of each page I set the $noHeader variable

```
$noHeader = true;
get_header();
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be asked here too:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"this doesn't work"* - please elaborate - what was expected and what happened

Comment: greg0ire thanks for the link. so used to using stackoverflow for everything didn't even know that existed.

Comment: Hamish - sorry for not elaborating. get_header() is a function specific to Wordpress, much like include in PHP. Got it all figured out now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Stephen said the `get_header` function doesn't give you access to variables in the scope you were in when you called it.  You can get around this by globalizing your variables before calling `get_header`.

```
<?php // In your theme file
global $noheader;
$noheader = true;
get_header();

<?php 
global $noheader; 
if(!$noheader) { 
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/feed.php'); 
}
```

This may seem messy, and it is, but there's no reason not to do it because WordPress uses global variables all over the place.  As I said in a comment to Stephen, this is better than directly including the `header.php` file in case you ever want to use parent/child themes.

Comment: Globalizing?  See #3:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273244/auditing-a-php-codebase/4273378#4273378

Comment: Thanks Stephen - yeah it sucks but it is kind of the way WordPress works anyways and WordPress development really starts to be a pain when you break out of their paradigms.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem.  The wordpress function `get_header();` does not evaluate local variables from the parent file in your included header file.  Change it to

```
// get_header(); //commented out for clarity of explanation
include 'header.php';
```

Honestly, there's no real reason that I've found to use `get_header();` over an `include`, anyway.

You might as well do this too:

```
// get_sidebar();
include 'sidebar.php';

// get_footer();
include 'footer.php';
```

Comment: You might want to use get_header if you're using the parent/child template theme paradigm, which is pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but like nickorhn said, I'm using parent/child themes in WP.

Comment: This is why I hate WordPress.  I ditched it for an OO/MVC solution and never looked back.

Comment: Never, never, **never** include the `header.php` file directly.  Always use `get_header()`.  This function calls a specific action hook that plug-ins and themes use to control the behavior of the header, add scripts, and make the site work.  If you include the PHP file directly, you're overriding this feature!

Comment: @EAMann Give me a solution that doesn't use the `global` keyword, and I'll listen.

Comment: If you're set on including `header.php` manually, at least call `do_action('get_header');` first.  This way your header call will still be pluggable.  But requiring the `global` keyword is a characteristic of how PHP handles variable scoping and there's no workaround so long as you're working with PHP.

Comment: "there's no workaround so long as you're working with PHP" I disagree.  I dev PHP projects professionally, and I never use the global keyword.  Though, I'm usually working with 99% object oriented code and only 1% procedural code.